# Make a New Double from Hashmap Values

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error :

> cannot find symbol, symbol: variable values, locations variable planet of type Map< String,Double >

on this line `Double[] Total = new Double [planet.values];`

Here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Double> planet = new HashMap();

    Double Weight = 205.00;

    planet.put("Earth", 1.00);
    planet.put("Moon", .378);
    planet.put("Mercury", .166);
    planet.put("Jupiter", 2.364);
    planet.put("Venus", .907);
    planet.put("Uranus", .889);

    System.out.println("Amount of gravity on each planet: " + planet + "\n");  


    Double[] Total = new Double [planet.values];
    System.out.println(planet.values());
```

Comment: What are u doing exactly? Are u trying to sum-up all planet's weight? Anyways, `values` is not a field in `HashMap` class so it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Map doesn't have any public field named `value`. So `planet.value` is invalid. If you want to initialize an array which has a length equal to the size of the map, use `size()`:

```
Double[] total = new Double[planet.size()];
```

Also, please respect tha Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I was actually hoping to multiply the values with double weight.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to `planet.values()` instead of 'planet.values', you are trying to access the field not calling the method.

So this will be your code:

```
Collection<Double> values = planet.values();
Double[] total = values.toArray(new Double[values.size()]);
```

By the way, an array's `toString()` method does not render values. If you want to write the values to console use `Arrays.toString(array)`.